# Filling in a Canvas with different colours depending on the button pressed

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to create a simple interactive widget, where I want to fill in a canvas upon clicking a button. I have Blue, Red, Green with hexcodes listed. I have the functions listed, and the fill listed but it doesn't change anything when I click the buttons.

//HTML

```
        <form>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
        <button onclick="changeblue()" class="canbut">Blue</button>
        <button onclick="changered()" class="canbut">Red</button>
        <button onclick="changegreen()" class="canbut">Green</button>
        </form>
```

//Js

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function changeblue (){
  ctx.fillStyle = "#0066FF";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function changered(){
ctx.fillStyle ="#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function changegreen (){
ctx.fillStyle ="#00cc00";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDLlS.png)

Comment: Even when I remove the form, or change it to type="button" the canvas still stays white when I click the buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the form tag, or add a preventDefault to your JS code

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function changeblue(e) {
  ctx.fillStyle = "#0066FF";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function changered() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function changegreen() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "#00cc00";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="300" style="border:2px solid black"></canvas>
<button onclick="changeblue()" class="canbut">Blue</button>
<button onclick="changered()" class="canbut">Red</button>
<button onclick="changegreen()" class="canbut">Green</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped. I am unsure but when I moved the javascript into the HTML instead of referencing the source likeso <script src="scripts/java.js"></script> 

and instead putting my function into the HTML it worked. I am unsure why the referencing from my js did not work, but I guess I'll try to figure that out now.

Comment: You have to check if you wrote the correct destination of your JS file into the script tag, it should work then, btw you're welcome